# Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong group ID, wrong artifact ID, wrong version

Tags: java, maven, plugins

The pom of the my maven plugin is as below.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.xmaven</groupId>
<artifactId>pig-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version>
<properties>
    <mavenVersion>3.2.1</mavenVersion>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.3</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-site-plugin.version>3.4</maven-site-plugin.version>
    <maven-assembly-plugin.version>2.6</maven-assembly-plugin.version>
    <maven-shade-plugin.version>2.4.2</maven-shade-plugin.version>
    <hadoop.version>2.7.3.2.6.1.0-129</hadoop.version>
    <hive.version>2.1.1</hive.version>
    <pig.version>0.16.0.2.6.1.0-129</pig.version>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>HDPReleases</id>
        <name>HDP Releases</name>
        <url>http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>HDPReleasesPublic</id>
        <name>HDP Releases</name>
        <url>http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/public/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>HDPJettyHadoop</id>
        <name>HDP Releases</name>
        <url>http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/jetty-hadoop/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>${mavenVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
        <version>${mavenVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twdata.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>mojo-executor</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-provider-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
            <artifactId>pigunit</artifactId>
            <version>${pig.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
            <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
            <version>${pig.version}</version>
            <classifier>h2</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xmaven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-build-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-site-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-assembly-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-descriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>descriptor</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>help-descriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>helpmojo</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am able to successfully install the plugin into local m2. However when I am trying to use this plugin in my project, it is giving me below error,

```
Invalid plugin descriptor for com.xmaven:pig-maven-plugin:2.0.0 (/Users/tkmahyt/.m2/repository/com/xmaven/pig-maven-plugin/2.0.0/pig-maven-plugin-2.0.0.jar), Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong group ID: org.apache.maven.plugins, Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong artifact ID: maven-resources-plugin, Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong version: 3.0.2 -> [Help 1]
```

Invalid plugin descriptor for com.xmaven:pig-maven-plugin:2.0.0 (/Users/tkmahyt/.m2/repository/com/xmaven/pig-maven-plugin/2.0.0/pig-maven-plugin-2.0.0.jar), 
Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong group ID: org.apache.maven.plugins, Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong artifact ID: maven-resources-plugin, Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong version: 3.0.2 -> [Help 1]

Anyone face this issue earlier ?

Is there any maven version issue in my plugin POM ?

Comment: What is the purpose of adding `maven-resources-plugin` as a dependency?

Comment: @ujulu,  I am using below packages in my class, import org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException;
import org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenResourcesExecution;
import org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenResourcesFiltering;